# Unknown column 'H' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I have tried everything I can think of to get query to recognize the `WHERE` clause.

`$sn` equals H-001 and `sn` is the column name

Here is the query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `insp` WHERE sn = $sn") or die(mysql_error());
```

I can get everything off the table if I don't use the `WHERE` clause. I can get the result if I make `$sn` a straight number with no letters of hyphen. I think I need something for the `WHERE` to recognize `H-001` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The string must be contained within quotes.

So, the sql you need looks like:
"SELECT * FROM insp WHERE sn = 'H-001'"

Try this:

```
$sn = "H-001";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM insp WHERE sn = '" . $sn . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Damn!! I'm 3 seconds too late :P

Comment: thanks guys.  I have tried that also.  What i have been able to figure out so far is that if i go to MySQLAdmin and manually enter the $sn then the query works.  or if i write out $sn = "H-001" then insert it into the database the query works.  But when I get $sn passed from a form and insert it into the database the query does not work.  I can look at the database and see the entries but the only ones i can pull down are the ones that i hard coded.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I found that by passing the variable from page to page that a space was being added to the variable. I used:
$sn=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $sn); and var_dump($sn); to strip the space and to check what was being posed.  Wow  5 full days trying to find this. Thanks to everybody who answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose your variable in inverted commas.

Which makes the code as

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `insp` WHERE `sn` = "'.$sn.'"') or die(mysql_error());
```

**Also please start using the new Mysqli functions or the PDO, as soon as possible.**

*Since the mysql native functions are deprecated and pretty **unsecure**.*

**Update:-** Since you mention the form input, maybe try typecasting the value as shown below.

```
//suppose the value is coming from $_POST['srno'];

$sn = (string) $_POST['srno'];

.....
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried this format also with no luck.  It only works with hard coded variable.  HMMM not sure.  I've tried to change the variable $sn to a string and see if the query would recognize that but it only works if i write it out as $sn="H-001"  it i pass it to the database from a form it doesn't work.

Comment: @BryanCombs I just introduced (updated my answer) a few backquote and reversed the inverted commas, should work IMHO.